# Redirect customer if he has an incomplete payment

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a restricted page using Cashier. In a nutshell I would like the page to start a subscription to have these limitations:

- Accessible to users who do not have a subscription
- Not accessible to users who have an incomplete invoice/subscription and therefore an open invoice.

This is my code:

```
if(Auth::user()->subscribed('default')) {
   return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'You already have an active subscription right now.');
}

if(Auth::user()->subscribed('default') || Auth::user()->subscription('default')->hasIncompletePayment()){
   return redirect()->route('account.invoices')->with('warning', 'You have a payment invoice for a pending subscription. Make payment or cancel.');
}
```

With this code of mine the only problem is when I try to access the page with a user who has no subscription, this error appears:

> Call to a member function hasIncompletePayment() on null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Auth::user()->subscribed('default')) {
   return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'You already have an active subscription right now.');
}

if(!empty(Auth::user()->subscription('default'))){
   if(Auth::user()->subscribed('default') || Auth::user()->subscription('default')->hasIncompletePayment()){
      return redirect()->route('account.invoices')->with('warning', 'You have a payment invoice for a pending subscription. Make payment or cancel.');
   }
}
```

Check subscription == null with empty